# after a for loop that give me differents dictionary how to find the dictionary with the max value?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I want to find the dictionary with the max value after a for loop

I have a list L that after a for loop (for L in list:) give me 3 dict:

```
{a:1}
{b:2}
{c:3}
```

how to print out {c:3}

I try the function .append to create a nested dictionary and try to do a loop with this nested dict but the function append doesn't work for dict.

how to print out:
{{a:1}, {b:2}, {c:3}}

or how to print out a list with all dict?
[{a:1}, {b:2}, {c:3}]

and how to print out:
{c:3}

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do an update so the dicts concatenate, for example:

```
dict1 = {'a':1}
dict2 = {'b':2}
dict3 = {'c':3}

dict2.update(dict3)
dict1.update(dict2)
```

this should result in a single dict

```
>>>>print(dict1)
>>>>{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
```

After that you can create a function or you can do a for loop to iterate the actual dict, I tried something like this:

```
def maxValueDict(values): #Function that recives a dict
    act = 0 #use to evaluate
    max_value=  {} #dict that will become the max value
    for key,value in values.items(): #we iterate the items   
        if  value > act: #if the value is bigger than the actual value
            act = value #we update the actual value
            max_value.clear() #we clean the dict
            max_value[key] = value #we add the new key and the value

    return max_value #return the final value
```

So the final result will be something like this:

```
maxValue = maxValueDict(dict1)

>>print(dict1)
>>{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
>>print(maxValue)
>>{'c':3}
```

Comment: Thanks! But after my for loop with my real data I have 100 different dictionaries. Is there a way to storage all dictionary in a list or other dictionary (nested dictionary) during the for loop? I tried to do a empty list and append but this function doesn’t work for dictionary

Answer (score -1):

You can consider this code :

```py
objects = [{"a": 1},
           {"b": 2},
           {"c": 3}]

to_print = objects[0]
for obj in objects:
    key = list(obj.keys())[0]  # Takes the first key of object, in this case,  "a", "b", or "c"
    tp_key = list(to_print.keys())[0]
    if obj[key] > to_print[tp_key]:
        to_print = obj
print(obj)
```

Output : `{'c': 3}`

Comment: but how to create a list with all the dictionary after a for loop? what code do you use to create objects?

Comment: Wait, what ? Can you share you whole ``for`` loop to see what you're iterating on  ?